# Weird Shadows In Render And Material Doesnt Show Up As Expected

Tags: materials, shaders, shadows

When I render the object, the shadows are looking weird. Also, I expect the outer part of the cable to look like shiny metal, but it is not what I expect.[image]

Can someone please tell me if there is any way to fix these problems.

Comment: Could you please show an image of your render settings, or post a .blend?

Comment: I managed to fix it by deleting the noise texture of the outer material